# Postgres select distinct of cartesian product

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, distinct-values, distinct-on

How to select from two columns such that each value is seen only once?

For example. From this table:

```
Column A                             Column B
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
11c32339-1b77-46e1-9215-0b1d4ec0b1d3 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1
39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
94e66d74-f0ce-472b-ad68-a98e267038b8 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
ab8130c7-e6a3-46cc-9ebc-0f8aca698169 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1
ab8130c7-e6a3-46cc-9ebc-0f8aca698169 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
94e66d74-f0ce-472b-ad68-a98e267038b8 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1
02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
11c32339-1b77-46e1-9215-0b1d4ec0b1d3 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
ab8130c7-e6a3-46cc-9ebc-0f8aca698169 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
94e66d74-f0ce-472b-ad68-a98e267038b8 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
```

Pull out this (both A and B distinct):

```
02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
ab8130c7-e6a3-46cc-9ebc-0f8aca698169 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1
94e66d74-f0ce-472b-ad68-a98e267038b8 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
```

I know there's a few combinations possible, I want *any* one of them but not all of them.

The table is made from a subset of cartesian product of distinct values of B and distinct values of A.

I have been meddling with window functions and group by's and have not gotten it to work yet.

Comment: I'd perhaps check out DISTINCT ON.

Comment: where is '39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2' and '11c32339-1b77-46e1-9215-0b1d4ec0b1d3' from your column A? 
i expect more records. or am i wrong?

Comment: Oh there was a third column, and they got filtered away! I should have said it's only a subset of a cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using window functions:

```
t=# create table so182(a text,b text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 23.926 ms
t=# copy so182 from stdin delimiter ' ';
t=# select distinct first_value(a) over (partition by b),b from so182;
             first_value              |                  b
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4 | 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510
 11c32339-1b77-46e1-9215-0b1d4ec0b1d3 | c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed
 39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2 | 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1
(3 rows)
```

distinct on:

```
t=# select distinct on (b) b,a from so182;
                  b                   |                  a
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 7495fc05-e244-426c-bdae-a5ee121be510 | 02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4
 7b9fb1b0-61d4-4424-af83-33b1b7e77bc1 | 39cb3ebd-bb7f-4023-ab44-65a0f3e4d6d2
 c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed | 11c32339-1b77-46e1-9215-0b1d4ec0b1d3
(3 rows)

Time: 0.263 ms
```

Comment: how about '94e66d74-f0ce-472b-ad68-a98e267038b8' and 
'ab8130c7-e6a3-46cc-9ebc-0f8aca698169' - those records will be lost - if you try to do a cartesian product with the result, there won't be the same data like it has been before

Comment: if I understand OP, ANY row A means we want any one, so the rest will be lost and this is wanted. Maybe I did not understand the post?..

Comment: I tried the distinct on (b) approach before but sometimes it gives duplicate in the a column so that's not it... It could potentially give:
`c597af82-58d5-4630-87e5-939898cc68ed , 02131d36-06cc-408e-9e40-1de65fbf37f4`, which is a duplicate in column A

Comment: @Eric true - If I specify the order with `order by` it does for sure :)

Comment: OK I tried a few times for the first solution I got a duplicate in column A too. I think because the DISTINCT is looking for distinct of rows a and b together, not A alone. If I put the window function inside "DISTINCT ON", then that prevents the duplicate but sometimes ends up with 2 rows instead of 3.

Comment: sorry - it was not clear from the post that values in column A should be distinct - I thought any A would do

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I cannot check right now if it works, but how about:

1. Creating 2 temporary tables like:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #ColumnA(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, columna varchar(30))
   CREATE TABLE #ColumnB(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, columnb varchar(30))
   ```
2. Filling them like:

   ```
    INSERT INTO ColumnA SELECT DISTINCT columna FROM OriginalTable
    INSERT INTO ColumnB SELECT DISTINCT columnb FROM OriginalTable
   ```
3. Joining:

   ```
   SELECT a.columna, b.columnb FROM ColumnA a OUTER JOIN ColumnB b ON a.id = b.id
   ```

It's not pretty, but should work. In point 1 I wrote table names with # - it seems to be creating temporary tables. Also AUTO_INCREMENT could be different in different dbms' (in postgres "id serial" is enough for this column).
I can check it later if there are no better answers.